# ASP.NET scheduler

Tags: asp.net, scheduling, scheduler

I need to integrate a scheduler (for instance, something like [Doodle](http://www.doodle.com)) into my ASP.NET website, preferably as an open source control\application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice one here:  http://www.daypilot.org/open-source.html

Although a Google search for "Calendar Scheduler" will turn up many more.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I am looking for. What I'm really after is a [Doodle](http://doodle.com/)-like control\application, where one (administrator) can set up an event and allocate time slots for others (participants) to choose from what is the most convenient time for themselves to take part in that event.

Comment: Ah... Sorry.  I''m not familiar with any.  I can withdraw my answer if you want to "un-accept" it, and maybe someone else will have a better one.

Comment: Yes, sorry. My question, as I initially put it, was probably too ambiguous.

Comment: DayPilot turned out to be an excellent control to adjust in order to produce a functionally Doodle-like scheduler. Thank you.